# How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table with some rows in. Every row has a date-field. Right now, it may be duplicates of a date. I need to delete all the duplicates and only store the row with the highest `id`. How is this possible using a SQL query?

Now:

```
date      id
'07/07'   1
'07/07'   2
'07/07'   3
'07/05'   4
'07/05'   5
```

What I want:

```
date      id
'07/07'   3
'07/05'   5
```

Comment: From the data you sent, you end up with two not three rows! 07/05 is repeated.

Answer (score 32):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY date);
```

Comment: Wow, did I go a roundabout way or what? This is definitely the best way to do this.

Comment: I thought your way was a bit too complicated... But honestly, I wanted to do it first using 3 queries instead of just this one.

Comment: This query is also useful for this answer:  SELECT date,
COUNT(date) AS NumOccurrences
FROM table
GROUP BY date HAVING ( COUNT(date) > 1 )

Comment: @djangofan: almost, you just hvae to select id instead of COUNT(date).

Comment: That however wouldn't work in MySQL due to its stupid limitations on sub-selects.

Comment: Depending on your data, this query can take a LOT longer than the one suggested by iddqd.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have comment rights, so here's my comment as an answer in case anyone comes across the same problem:

In SQLite3, there is an implicit numerical primary key called "rowid", so the same query would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid NOT IN
(SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM table GROUP BY date);
```

this will work with any table even if it does not contain a primary key column called "id".

Answer (score 3):

For mysql,postgresql,oracle better way is SELF JOIN.

```
Postgresql:
DELETE FROM table t1 USING table t2 WHERE t1.date=t2.date AND t1.id<t2.id;

MySQL        
DELETE FROM table
USING table, table as vtable
WHERE (table.id < vtable.id)
AND (table.date=vtable.date)
```

SQL aggregate (max,group by) functions almost always are very slow.