# Delete duplicate rows (don't delete all duplicate)

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I am using postgres.
I want to delete Duplicate rows.
The condition is that , 1 copy from the set of duplicate rows would not be deleted.

i.e : if there are 5 duplicate records then 4 of them will be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)

Comment: how ironic! lol 'possible duplicate of how to delete duplicates'...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the steps described in this article: [Removing duplicates from a PostgreSQL database](http://www.siafoo.net/article/64).

It describes a situation when you have to deal with huge amount of data which isn't possible to `group by`.

A simple solution would be this:

```
DELETE FROM foo
       WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) --or max(id)
                        FROM foo
                        GROUP BY hash)
```

Where `hash` is something that gets duplicated.

Comment: doesn't this delete all the rows that don't have duplicates, too?

Comment: @pomarc no, because there's this little equals sign (=) before 1 that tells us that we want to take min(id) of all possible groups even those that contain only one member; so, no worries, you won't delete data that is not duplicated

Comment: is the having count (*) >=1 neccesary ? i got the same result if I execute : DELETE FROM foo
       WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id)
                        FROM foo
                        GROUP BY hash)

Comment: @grteibo you are absolutely right, that's the way the deduplication is usually done; I don't know why I didn't notice that before; the idea of this answer is not so much the idea of deduplication itself but the fact that we calculate a hash for all the columns that we want to group by and then remove duplicates

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from table
where not id in 
(select max(id) from table group by [duplicate row])
```

This is random (max Value) choice which row you need to keep.
If you have aggre whit this please provide more details

Answer (score 2):

The fastest is  is join to the same table.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-delete.html

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT,id2 INT);
CREATE TABLE
mapy=# INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,2);
INSERT 0 1
mapy=# INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,3);
INSERT 0 1
mapy=# INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,4);
INSERT 0 1

DELETE FROM test t1 USING test t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id2<t2.id2;
DELETE 2
mapy=# SELECT * FROM test;
 id | id2 
----+-----
  1 |   4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table t1 
where rowid > (SELECT min(rowid) FROM table t2 group by 
               t2.id,t2.name );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE f1 from foo as f1, foo as f2 
       where f1.duplicate_column= f2.duplicate_column
             AND f1.id > f2.id;
```