# Mistakenly added duplicate records. How do I delete them?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

**EDIT**

This query is not working, any idea why?

```
select `key`, distinct `filename`, `url`, `processed`, `timestamp` from snaps;
```

It says to check syntax near `'distinct`filename``

---

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `snaps` (
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `url` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `processed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `key` (`key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I exported the rows of the table and mistakenly imported it back into the same table. So now I have two rows of everything. **`filename` is unique.**

How can I delete the duplicate records?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT into a temporary table, flush the first one, and move them back again.

Comment: That's embarrassingly simple. I tried the query in the edit but it's not working. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your distinct goes at the beginning, after SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the original unduplicated rows of the table, can you not just

`TRUNCATE <table>` and then reimport them?

Answer (score 0):

Does second set of rows has an identical timestamp from the insert? If so, you could DELETE based on that timestamp.

Alternately, you could `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`, delete the last half, `TRUNCATE TABLE` and then `LOAD DATA INFILE`.