# How do I delete duplicate rows and keep the first row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I made a mistake and I have unwanted duplicates.

I have a table with 4 key fields. `A1`, `k1`, `k2`, `k3`.

`A1` is auto increment and the primary key.

the combination of `k1`, `k2` and `k3` is supposed to be unique and I have to delete the duplicate rows before I create a unique index. Some rows have one duplicate, some have many.

```
SELECT CONCAT(k1, k2, k) AS dup_value
  FROM myviews
 GROUP BY dup_value
HAVING (COUNT(dup_value) > 1)
```

shows me duplicates values that I need to deal with. But now I don't know how to keep one and delete the rest of each duplicate set.

Comment: There are a LOT of questions regarding this problem.  This should be closed as duplicate - FAST.  Do a search for "delete duplicate rows."  Here's [the first result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate) for me.

Comment: @rockerest Interestingly I tried the solution you linked to first and it doesn't work with MySQL.  The answer from OMG Ponies did work for me on MySQL so that's where my +1 goes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Backup your data, then...

[MySQL supports JOINs in DELETE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).  If you want to keep the first of the duplicates:

```
DELETE a
  FROM MYVIEWS a
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(t.a1) AS min_a1, t.k1, t.k2, t.k3
          FROM MYVIEWS t
      GROUP BY t.k1, t.k2, t.k3
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON b.k1 = a.k1
                              AND b.k2 = a.k2
                              AND b.k3 = a.k3
                              AND b.min_a1 != a.a1
```

If you want to keep the last of the duplicates:

```
DELETE a
  FROM MYVIEWS a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.a1) AS max_a1, t.k1, t.k2, t.k3
          FROM MYVIEWS t
      GROUP BY t.k1, t.k2, t.k3
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON b.k1 = a.k1
                              AND b.k2 = a.k2
                              AND b.k3 = a.k3
                              AND b.max_a1 != a.a1
```

Comment: I get an error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'myviews' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @sdfor: Sorry, forgot about that limitation -- try the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new table with the same structure but empty, then create the unique key on it, then do a `INSERT IGNORE` / `SELECT * FROM` the original table into the new table, then delete the original table.

`INSERT IGNORE` will automatically ignore any primary or unique key issues and just skip the duplicates.

Comment: Not an ideal practice for Production systems -- queries will be depending on the old table, and there can't be more than one table in the database with the same name.  This would require an outage.

Comment: Very true. I assumed OP's wasn't in production yet, due to altering keys and deleting tons of rows, but I shouldn't assume!

Answer (score 2):

Someting like this?

```
DELETE FROM myviews WHERE EXISTS(SELECT CONCAT(k1, k2, k) AS dup_value
FROM myviews
GROUP BY dup_value
HAVING (COUNT(dup_value) > 1));
```

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your question. Is it duplicity within one tuple?

Comment: this is wrong (at least relative to the question) becouse it deletes all rows on duplicated sets

Comment: In addition to deleting all rows instead of all but one (as @LuisSiquot mentions) this will cause an error when run on tables: SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

You need a separator in your concat function, because otherwise "a", "b", and "cd" is the same as "abcd", "", "".