# delete mysql duplicate enty and use the most up2date one based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have 2 entries in mysql database which has duplicate entries under 'hwaddr' column as shown in the added screenshot.

how do i search for duplicates based on 'hwaddr' column and leave only the most up2date one based on 'timestamp' column? (delete the old one)

[image: mysql data screenshot]

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-select-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest

Answer (score 0):

Try this to delete:

```
DELETE FROM `list` WHERE `id`IN (SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT MAX( id )
    FROM `list`
    GROUP BY ip
    HAVING COUNT( ip ) >1) AS e)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming greater number primary key (id) will have latest timestamp, so you can use below query which is more optimized and will delete all duplicate records not just one, excluding latest one.

```
DELETE b.* 
FROM mytable b 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable GROUP BY hwaddr) a ON a.id=b.id 
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

This is single query command even for production server there can be better options.

Answer (score 0):

listing hwaddr duplication

```
SELECT * FROM `general2` WHERE hwaddr in ( SELECT hwaddr FROM general2 GROUP BY hwaddr HAVING COUNT( * ) >1 )
```

listing what will be deleted

```
select t1.* FROM general2 t1, general2 t2 WHERE t1.hwaddr=t2.hwaddr  AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
```

deleting by hwaddr leaving the most updated by timestamp.

```
DELETE t1 FROM general2 t1, general2 t2 WHERE t1.hwaddr=t2.hwaddr  AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
```