# remove duplicate data from sql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a sql database named "data" and a table "disk", where there are 5 columns

```
CREATE TABLE `disk` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mag` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

the "mag" column has a some of the duplicates.

and I want to delete the complete row where mag column is same.

note: let's say mag column has 1,2,3,4,4,5.... I want to delete a single 4 from it which is duplicate. means I don't want to completely delete both the 4. one "4" must be kept.

What should the query for it look like?

Comment: Which id = 4 row to keep?

Comment: Consider to include sql for DDL and sample data in your questions, so it will help other members give you answer faster and more precise

Comment: both are same doesn't matter @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following..

**Creating new table and keeping random row :**

1. first copy table `disk`(unique data) to temp table `disk2`.
2. drop table `disk`.
3. rename temp table `disk2` to `disk`.

   ```
   create table disk2 select * from disk group by d;

   drop table disk;

   rename table disk2 to disk;
   ```

**NOTE :** Here we using `group by` with `*` because OP does not care which row to keep.

**Creating new table and keeping row with min or max id :**
Another way to do this while keeping row with `min` or `max` id

```
/*copy data from disk to temp table disk2*/
create table disk2 select * from disk
    where id in (select min(id) from disk group by d);
/*drop table disk*/
drop table disk;
/*rename temp table to disk*/
rename table disk2 to disk;
```

**UPDATE:**  Another way to do this

**Deleting duplicates from existing table**

```
    /*first create a dups table for duplicates*/
    create table dups select * from disk
        where id not in (select min(id) from disk group by d);
    /*now delete all rows which are present in dups table*/
    delete from disk where id in (select id from dups);
    /*now delete the dups table*/
    drop table dups;
```

Comment: it worked well but still has a problem... my server does not allow me to make more than 5000 changes in the database in an hour. so creating a new table with around 10000 rows and then renaming the table, would not work...

Answer (score 6):

try  this below to delete  duplicate with same d column and keep one row with lowest id value: :

```
DELETE d1 
FROM  disk d1, disk d2 
WHERE d1.id > d2.id AND 
      d1.d = d2.d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE disk
FROM disk
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT id,
               d,
               CASE WHEN d = @prevd 
                       THEN @id:=@id+1
                    ELSE @id:=1
               END AS rankNum,
               @prevd:=d AS prd
       FROM disk, (SELECT @prevd:=NULL,@id:=NULL) t
      ) t1
ON disk.id = t1.id
WHERE rankNum >= 2;
```

For Demo Follow the below link:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=318e94a135853fcd15b14e4b8bbf1fdc

Comment: d is a text field and second thing is it compiled without error but it didnt remove any row... 0 rows affected

Comment: CREATE TABLE `disk` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mag` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


this my actual table

Comment: I edited my answer try it again and show me how it's not working. @user9673975

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from disk
where id  in 
(
select id 
from task
group by id 
having count(id) >1
)
```

Comment: Will not delete any rows at all.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to create any temporary tables**

I hope this will work for you

```
DELETE ColumnName
FROM TableName
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT  MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) Duplicate on Duplicate.ID = TableName.ID
WHERE TableName.ID < Duplicate.lastId;
```

Please also check the following link your for more suggestions

[MySQL delete duplicate records but keep latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)