# Delete duplicate rows in MySQL where all columns match. Keep latest row

Tags: mysql

This is a topic, which has been discussed several times in here, but for me it's difficult to understand how to delete duplicated rows in our MySQL database. Yes, I have seen many examples, but they are simplified to 2 columns etc. and the solution is most of the time just query, which has not been explained. As I want to securely clean our database. I have backed up my table, and now I wan't to delete duplicated rows (as I have many of them). Below is a snippet of query, which I have tried, and it is fairly simple:  *if duplicated rows, pick latest row and show ID of the row.*

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Raw_Validated_backup GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, ... col_n-1 having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Now, as I have selected latest row of duplicated rows, I 'just' have to delete the duplicated rows. Easier said that done, if you ask me. This is a query written by @Jose Rui Santos:

```
delete test
  from test
 inner join (
  select max(id) as lastId, email
    from test
   where email in (
              select email 
                from test
               group by email
              having count(*) > 1
       )
   group by email
) duplic on duplic.email = test.email
 where test.id < duplic.lastId;
```

He replied to this post: [MySQL delete duplicate records but keep latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest)

Question is, how do I exactly delete duplicated rows and keep the latest? Prefer to be in a pseudo like format, so others can learn from this as well. For example:

```
DELETE table FROM database
```

And not specific like:

```
DELETE email FROM city
```

**MySQL Queries**

EXAMPLE 1:

```
DELETE t1 FROM Raw_Validated_backup AS t1 INNER JOIN Raw_Validated_backup AS t2 
      ON t1.time_start=t2.time_start 
      AND t1.time_end=t2.time_end 
      AND t1.first_temp_lpn=t2.first_temp_lpn 
      AND t1.first_WL=t2.first_WL 
      AND t1.first_temp_lpn_validated=t2.first_temp_lpn_validated 
      AND t1.second_temp_lpn=t2.second_temp_lpn 
      AND t1.second_WL=t2.second_WL 
      AND t1.second_temp_lpn_validated=t2.second_temp_lpn_validated 
      AND t1.third_temp_lpn=t2.third_temp_lpn 
      AND t1.third_WL=t2.third_WL 
      AND t1.third_temp_lpn_validated=t2.third_temp_lpn_validated 
      AND t1.first_temp_rising=t2.first_temp_rising 
      AND t1.first_WR=t2.first_WR 
      AND t1.first_temp_rising_validated=t2.first_temp_rising_validated 
      AND t1.second_temp_rising=t2.second_temp_rising 
      AND t1.second_WR=t2.second_WR 
      AND t1.second_temp_rising_validated=t2.second_temp_rising_validated 
      AND t1.third_temp_rising=t2.third_temp_rising 
      AND t1.third_WR=t2.third_WR 
      AND t1.third_temp_rising_validated=t2.third_temp_rising_validated 
      AND t1.id<t2.id;
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
DELETE FROM Raw_Validated_backup WHERE id NOT IN ( 
SELECT max(id) FROM Raw_Validated_backup 
GROUP BY time_start, time_end, first_temp_lpn, first_WL, first_temp_lpn_validated, second_temp_lpn, second_WL, second_temp_lpn_validated, third_temp_lpn, third_WL, third_temp_lpn_validated, first_temp_rising, first_WR, first_temp_rising_validated, second_temp_rising, second_WR, second_temp_rising_validated, third_temp_rising, third_WR, third_temp_rising_validated )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------------+------+------+------+
| id | email            | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+----+------------------+------+------+------+
|  1 | user@example.org |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|  2 | user@example.org |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|  3 | user@example.org |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|  4 | user@example.org |    2 |    3 |    4 |
+----+------------------+------+------+------+

mysql> DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1 INNER JOIN test AS t2 
    ON t1.email=t2.email AND t1.col2=t2.col2 AND t1.col3=t2.col3 AND t1.col4=t2.col4 
    AND t1.id<t2.id;

mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------------+------+------+------+
| id | email            | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+----+------------------+------+------+------+
|  4 | user@example.org |    2 |    3 |    4 |
+----+------------------+------+------+------+
```

Explanation: The condition in the join looks for a row `t2` such that the id is greater, and all other columns are equal. If such a row is found, then `t1` must not be the row with the greatest id among the duplicates, therefore row `t1` should be deleted.

Comment: is test = table?

Comment: That was the table name in the example you posted above by Jose Rui Santos.

Comment: Tried the command, and unfortunately it didn't work: Will paste the code on my question post

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't tell me enough. Did it return an error? If so, what was the error? Did it delete the wrong rows? Did it delete nothing?

Comment: The query is running for some time, and stops with no error. Seems like nothing really has happened. To easily check, I've duplicated a row, but when running query both of the rows are still there. They are identical, where only the id is different

Answer (score 0):

The final solution in @Jose Rui Santos's answer will do exactly what you need.

```
DELETE
FROM table_name
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY email
)
```

It will select all the IDs of the latest records for each group (the grouping being done on email in this case, but it can be on all of your columns as well), and then delete all the records that are not in the result of the query.

You can make sure it is, in fact, going to delete the right results by first just running the select:

```
SELECT max(id)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY email
```

This will show you everything that won't be deleted.

Comment: is test = table?

Comment: Yes, it's the table you want to delete from

Comment: Throws me this error: 'You can't specify target table 'Raw_Validated_backup' for update in FROM clause' Will update query on my post, so you can see what I've done