# How to delete all duplicate records from sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

i have table in sql
and I want to remove duplicate records
but remove all duplicate records

| First name | last name |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| a | b |
| a | c |

after run

| First name | last name |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL delete duplicate records but keep latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select first_name, last_name
from t
group by first_name, last_name
having count(*) = 1;
```