# MySql remove the rows that have a duplicate column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

This is my **domains** table:

```
domain       | ip
-------------|-----------
example.com  | 0.0.0.0
-------------|-----------
example1.com | 1.1.1.1
-------------|-----------
example2.com | 2.2.2.2
-------------|-----------
example3.com | 3.3.3.3
-------------|-----------
example2.com | 9.9.9.9
-------------|-----------
example4.com | 4.4.4.4
-------------|-----------
example3.com | 3.3.3.3
-------------|-----------
```

I want to delete the rows where are duplicate domains and keep the first value of ip, so I must have a table like this finally:

```
domain       | ip
-------------|-----------
example.com  | 0.0.0.0
-------------|-----------
example1.com | 1.1.1.1
-------------|-----------
example2.com | 2.2.2.2
-------------|-----------
example3.com | 3.3.3.3
-------------|-----------
example4.com | 4.4.4.4
-------------|-----------
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yes. I created a new table with DISTINCT(domain) and after that I tried to run a php script to get for each of that value the first ip with LIMIT 0,1 but the script takes years since I have more than 400.000 rows in the database. I am not an mysql expert

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103212/how-do-i-delete-duplicate-rows-and-keep-the-first-row) and others on StackOverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete duplicate rows and keep the first row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103212/how-do-i-delete-duplicate-rows-and-keep-the-first-row)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `INET_ATON` and `INET_NTOA` with `GROUP BY` to get least IP for each domain like this:

```
SELECT 
    domain, INET_NTOA(MIN(INET_ATON(ip)))
FROM
    domains t1
GROUP BY domain;
```

`MIN(IP)` will not work the way you'd expect.

You can perform a delete using the above like this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM domains t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        domain, INET_NTOA(MIN(INET_ATON(ip))) ip
    FROM
        domains t1
    GROUP BY domain) t2 ON t1.domain = t2.domain AND t1.ip <> t2.ip;
```

Please note that if there are multiple rows with least IP for a domain, all of them will be kept.

You can alternatively create a new table to store distinct rows:

```
CREATE TABLE domains_new(domain varchar(100), IP varchar(30))
SELECT 
    domain, INET_NTOA(MIN(INET_ATON(ip)))
FROM
    domains t1
GROUP BY domain;
```

Comment: This select seem to be good. The thing is that I want either to remove the rest of the rows, either copy this data into a separate identical table.

Comment: The second query does not work. It doesn't delete enought rows. The thing is that the select works.

Comment: @paul doesn't work how? I've tried it and it deleted the row `example2.com | 9.9.9.9`. If you are talking about two rows with `example3.com | 3.3.3.3` values, I already mentioned that in the answer, there is no way to delete those, without creating a temporary table, loading distinct data into it, clearing table and loading back or simply select distinct

Comment: The delete query does not work. So I have 452616 records. If I make the select I get 421175 records (meaning that 31441 are duplicates). But when I try to run the delete query, I get " 0 rows deleted"

Comment: Is there any way to use that select that you made first time and copy that data into another table? I will be fine with that also.

Comment: @paul Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks man. This solved my problem. I will just remove the other table and rename this new one and all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

So to delete the dups, assuming your table has an primary key called `id`,

```
DELETE FROM domains 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT dyt.id FROM domains oyt, domains dyt
WHERE oyt.id < dyt.id
AND oyt.domain = dyt.domain
AND oyt.ip = dyt.ip)
```

Comment: the table does not have any primary id, it's exactly as you see in the question

Comment: Then creating a new table using `DISTINCT` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

if you assign each row a unique id

```
alter table domains add column id int first;
set @i = 0;
update domains set id=(@i:=@i+1);
```

then you may be able to do something like this:

```
delete from domains
where id not in (select id from 
(select id, domain, ip from domains group by domain having count(domain) > 1) as subq);
```

then just remove the key column

```
alter table domains drop column id;
```

Answer (score 0):

create the second collection with same structure and try this.

```
INSERT INTO second_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM domains
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH result AS (
    SELECT Domain,
           Ip,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Domain 
                                 ORDER BY p.Ip) AS rk
      FROM DomainsTable p)
SELECT r.Domain, r.Ip
  FROM result r
WHERE r.rk = 1
```