# Delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this

> Table1
>
> Id, Name

How can I write a query that delete all rows with duplicate names but keep the one with the lower Id?

Comment: create a new table with unique rows delete the old one, then rename the new one with the old name, maybe you should try to avoid adding duplicate entries

Comment: After you've done your cleanup, *add a UNIQUE constraint* on name, so you don't have to do this job again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete duplicate rows (don't delete all duplicate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
With Dups As
    (
    Select Id, Name
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By Name Order By Id ) As Num
    From Table1
    )
Delete Table1
Where Id In (
            Select Id
            From Dups
            Where Num > 1
            )
```

If using SQL Server 2000 and prior

```
Delete Table1
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table1 As T1
                Where T1.Name = Table1.Name
                Having Min( T1.Id ) <> Table1.Id
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

The duplicates can be removed with a simple self join query. The below script would do the trick for you.

```
delete t2
from Table1 t1
join Table1 t2
   on t1.Name = t2.Name
where t1.Id < t2.Id
```

This logic can be used for cases where duplicates need to be removed. We should avoid "cursor" as much as possible as it blocks the table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can  do this  with using cursors
the query might be like this

declare @id int
declare @name  nvarchar(30)

declare cr cursor for select id,name from idnametbl order by id

for update

open cr

fetch next from cr into @id,@name

while @@fetch_status=0

begin

delete from  idnametbl where id> @id and name=@name

fetch next from cr into @id,@name

end

close cr

deallocate cr