# SQL delete duplicate rows

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165895/delete-duplicate-rows)

Here is my table structure:

"Author" (varchar) |  "Points" (integer) |  "Body" (text)

The author is always the same and the Body is too. The same author entry will appear multiple times throughout the database with different bodies, so I cannot delete according to the author. However, the points column isn't always the same. I want the keep the row with the largest point value.

I am using SQLite3 and Python.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have tried this, but it just deletes all the rows.

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
        rows = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Author=? AND Body=? AND Nested=? AND Found=?', (row['Author'], row['Body'], row['Nested'], row['Found'],))
        for row2 in rows:
            delrow = row
            if (row['Upvotes'] <  row2['Upvotes'] or row['Downvotes'] < row2['Downvotes']):
                delrow = row2
            cur.execute("DELETE FROM Posts WHERE Author=? AND Body=? AND Upvotes=? AND Downvotes=? AND Nested=? AND Found=?", (delrow['Author'], delrow['Body'], delrow['Upvotes'], delrow['Downvotes'], delrow['Nested'], delrow['Found'],))
            dn += 1
            print "Deleted row ", dn
```

I have also tried this, but it didn't work.

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM Posts WHERE Upvotes NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Upvotes) FROM Posts GROUP BY Body);")
```

I am also committing all the changes so it is not that. The SQLite3 module is installed correctly and I can write on the db.

Comment: *Beep beep* Welcome back to Stack Overflow, friendly user.  Please ensure that all questions are worded in the form of questions.  Also, please be courteous and remember to accept answers to your questions.  Have a wonderful day.  *Beep*

Comment: What have you tried?  Duplicate row deletions are usually done with some sort of ranking function, like ROWNUMBER, partitioned over your author and body.

Comment: Try doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165895/delete-duplicate-rows, especially Vivek's answer. (Of course, you want to switch the direction of the inequality to get the largest point value.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in SQLite3 you don't have nice functions like `partition over row` so there's no way to do it in one query so you'll either have to do it procedurally or iteratively.

For performance reasons I would recommend extracting your full list of deletion potentials and then delete them en-masse, for eg.

```
# in your sql query
SELECT ROWID, AUTHOR, BODY
FROM   TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY AUTHOR, BODY, POINTS DESC
```

Then in your Python application, iterate through your result set, and store all non-first ROWIDs for the Author/Body combo (think CTRL-BREAK style programming), and once you're done building your set delete the row IDs.

Comment: You don't need a `partition over row` for this type of delete, since there is a column that varies (`points`).  You'd only need that if the rows were exactly identical, which they aren't.  I'd find it hard to believe that it would be more efficient to extract the data, process it in Python, and then push the results back to the db, rather than just doing it within the db.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to delete all but the highest points value, the following will do it just fine:

```
delete from test
  where exists (select * from test t2
                where test.author = t2.author
                and test.body = t2.body
                and test.points < t2.points);
```

It's a basic join to itself, and then deleting out all values that have the same author & body, but have a lower point value.

SqlFiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/64d62/3

Note:  The one caveat, is that if multiple author/body pairs have the same max point value, then all those values will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this *may* work:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
    WHERE author, body, points NOT IN (SELECT author, body, MAX(points) as points
        FROM TableName 
    GROUP BY author, body)
```

Run it as a SELECT query first to see if it will keepwhat you want.

Comment: That won't work unless the points column is unique.
What you could do is return `author, body, max(points)` from the inner select and in your where clause have `(author, body, points) not in [inner select]` which could work.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example per your suggestions.  I also add `body` to the `group by` statement b/c I think it would be necessary.

Comment: Ah yes you would need that in the `group by` otherwise it will fail. Missed that one.