# Find and remove duplicate rows by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, duplicates

I read all the relevant duplicated questions/answers and I found this to be the most relevant answer:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO temp(MAILING_ID,REPORT_ID) 
SELECT DISTINCT MAILING_ID,REPORT_IDFROM table_1
;
```

The problem is that I want to remove duplicates by col1 and col2, but also want to include to the insert all the other fields of table_1.

I tried to add all the relevant columns this way:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO temp(M_ID,MAILING_ID,REPORT_ID,
MAILING_NAME,VISIBILITY,EXPORTED) SELECT DISTINCT  
M_ID,MAILING_ID,REPORT_ID,MAILING_NAME,VISIBILITY,
EXPORTED FROM table_1
;


M_ID(int,primary),MAILING_ID(int),REPORT_ID(int),
MAILING_NAME(varchar),VISIBILITY(varchar),EXPORTED(int)
```

But it inserted all rows into temp (including duplicates)

Comment: Well for one thing -- do not use `INSERT IGNORE` in your case, 2nd --> How is your db table set up?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: @Neal updated my question with the actual field names and types

Answer (score 39):

The best way to delete duplicate rows by multiple columns is the simplest one:

**Add an UNIQUE index:**

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2,field3);
```

The IGNORE above makes sure that only the first found row is kept, the rest discarded.

(You can then drop that index if you need future duplicates and/or know they won't happen again).

Comment: MUCH easier than correlated subqueries.

Comment: As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.

Comment: in mysql 5.5 there is a bug that can be present.

use `set old_alter_table=1`
 see docs at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html 

Due to a bug related to Fast Index Creation (Bug #40344), ALTER IGNORE TABLE ... ADD UNIQUE INDEX does not delete duplicate rows. The IGNORE keyword is ignored. If any duplicate rows exist, the operation fails with a Duplicate entry error. A workaround is to set old_alter_table=1 prior to running an ALTER IGNORE TABLE ... ADD UNIQUE INDEX statement.

Comment: How would this works if I want to modify one column first. For example this is not working:
`ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE 
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 5) * 5), 
    id2)`

Comment: ALTER IGNORE has been deprecated

Answer (score 26):

This works perfectly in any version of MySQL including 5.7+.  It also handles the error `You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause` by using a double-nested subquery.  It only deletes ONE duplicate row (the later one) so if you have 3 or more duplicates, you can run the query multiple times.  It *never* deletes unique rows.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT calc_id FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS calc_id
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY identField1, identField2
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
  ) temp
)
```

I needed this query because I wanted to add a UNIQUE index on two columns but there were some duplicate rows that I needed to discard first.

Comment: `You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: It works since the `WHERE` clause uses double nesting. That's the magic that tricks the MySQL engine into allowing this query without creating a conflict.

Comment: keep in mind it will remove ONLY 1 duplicate if 1+ exists.

Answer (score 17):

**For Mysql:**

```sql
DELETE t1 FROM yourtable t1 
  INNER JOIN yourtable t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id 
    AND t1.identField1 = t2.identField1 
    AND t1.identField2 = t2.identField2;
```

Answer (score 7):

You will first need to find your duplicates by grouping on the two fields with a having clause.

```
    Select identField1, identField2, count(*) FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY identField1, identField2
          HAVING count(*) >1
```

If this returns what you want, you can then use it as a subquery and

```
  DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE field in (Select identField1, identField2, count(*) FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY identField1, identField2
          HAVING count(*) >1 )
```

Comment: Will this keep one of the duplicates rows? (I want to keep one, not delete any row that has a duplicate)

Comment: It will remove all of the duplicates. If you want to keep one, you can select a max or min of a field you aren't aggregating on. A quick google turned up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate?rq=1  which also links to other identical questions.

Comment: What if the table only has 2 columns and both columns are being grouped, how do I prevent deleting all duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This solution is an alternative & old school solution.**

---

If you couldn't achieve what you wanted, then you can try my "oldschool" method:

First, run this query to get the duplicate records:

```
select   column1,
         column2,
         count(*)
from     table
group by column1,
         column2
having   count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc
```

After that, select those results and paste them into the notepad++:

[image: select query]
[image: paste onto notepad]

Now by using the find and replace specialty of the notepad++ replace them with; first "delete" then "insert" queries like this (from now on, for security reasons, my values will be AAAA).

Special Note: Please make another new line for the end of the last line of your data inside notepad++ because regex matched the '\r\n' at the end of the each line:

[image]

Find what regex: `\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*\r\n`

Replace with string: `delete from table where column1 = $1 and column2 = $2; insert into table set column1 = $1, column2 = $2;\r\n`

Now finally, paste those queries to your MySQL Workbench's query console and execute. You will see only one occurrences of each duplicate record.

[image]

This answer is for a relation table constructed of just two columns without ID. I think you can apply it to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

you can always get the primary ids by grouping that two unique fields

`select count(*), id as count from table group by col a, col b having count(*)>1;`

and then

`delete from table where id in ( select count(*), id as count from table group by col a, col b having count(*)>1) limit maxlimit;`

you can also use `max()` in place of `limit`

Comment: what does the limit maxlimit do?

Comment: @Notflip that refers to how many duplicate rows you want to delete

Comment: you cannot use the same table for the nested query and the delete query.

Comment: This is not working @SudhanshuJain, have you tested this??

Answer (score 1):

In a large data set if you are selecting the multiple columns in the select clause ex:
`select x,y,z from table1`.
And the requirement is to remove duplicate based on two columns:from above example let y,z
then you may use below instead of using combo of "group by" and "sub query", which is bad in performance:

```
select x,y,z 
from (
select x,y,z , row_number() over (partition by y,z) as index_num
from table1) main
where main.index_num=1
```