# Find and remove duplicate rows by two columns where one of those columns is a TIMEDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find and remove duplicate rows by two columns in a table

one recommended solution is to put a unique index and then remove it, like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2,field3);
```

([Find and remove duplicate rows by two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340820/find-and-remove-duplicate-rows-by-two-columns))

One of the columns is DATETIME, and i want to use the date part of it as the 'unique' feature to remove duplicates by. How do I do that?

for example:

```
[column1] [column2]
[2020-01-01 11:11:11] [john]
[2020-01-01 16:11:11] [john]
[2020-07-07 17:17:11] [mike]
```

i want one of the first 2 rows to be deleted because the date part of the timestamp (in column1) and the name (column2) , are the same.

expected result:

```
[column1] [column2]
[2020-01-01 11:11:11] [john]
[2020-07-07 17:17:11] [mike]
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key column?

Comment: no primary key column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use exists logic here:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.column2 = t1.column2 AND
                    DATE(t2.column1) = DATE(t1.column1) AND
                    t2.column1 < t1.column1);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to delete any record for which we can find another record with the same name (`column2` value), same date, but an *earlier* timestamp, with time portion included.  This exists check would fail for a given name having the earliest timestamp value.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete t1
from your_table t1
left join
(
  select min(col1) mcol, col2
  from your_table
  group by col2
) tmp on t1.col1 = tmp.mcol 
     and t1.col2 = tmp.col2
where tmp.col2 is null
```