# How do I merge duplicate rows in my MySQL database, product IDs and their ratings

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a database which contains product ID's and their rating out of 5 customers have given them. Each row in the database represents 1 review. Its quite simple and has the product ID and a 1 in the column where the review was 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 star. It is laid out like this:

```
Product ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

1294518    | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

9226582    | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

3946583    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

7392588    | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

1196585    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

1196585    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

I want to merge the rows where I have duplicate product ID's. As per the example above there are two rows for product ID 1196585. In this case I would like to combine this into one row with a 2 under the 5 column to show this product has received two 5 star reviews.

To clarify I would like to modify the table in place so duplicate rows are combined, so that afterwards there are no duplicate product ID's and under each of the columns 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 I am left with the number of times each of these product ID's has received a 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 star review for example.

Please could you help me understand how this could be achieved with SQL?

Comment: Do you have a primary key on this table?  If not, can you make one at least temporarily?  If not, can the solution involve a temp table?

Comment: @BenPaton . . . Do you want to modify the table in place?  Or do you want to just retrieve the data with one row per product?

Comment: There is no primary key. Yes I want to modify the table in place.

Comment: 1. NORMALIZE YOUR DATA.

Comment: "Normalize your data" is not a good suggestion, because you don't know if he can normalize them, and you don't even know why they are not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple aggregation query:

```
select ProductId, sum(Rate_1) as Rate_1, sum(Rate_2) as Rate_3, sum(Rate_3) as Rate_3,
       sum(Rate_4) as Rate_4, sum(Rate_5) as Rate_5
from t
group by ProductId
```

I changed the ostensible names of your columns to names using standard characters.  `1` seems like a bad name for a column, for instance.

Comment: This doesn't fix the table. The original question asks to update the data.

Comment: @Jerome . . . The original question is ambiguous (at least in my opinion).  The OP should clarify what s/he means.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the data in your table, you can use the following statement:

```
UPDATE product p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT "Product ID" as id,
               SUM(product."1") AS s1,
               SUM(product."2") AS s2,
               SUM(product."3") AS s3,
               SUM(product."4") AS s4,
               SUM(product."5") AS s5
        FROM product
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING count(*) > 1) sums
    ON p.id = sums.id
SET p."1" = sums.s1, p."2" = sums.s2, p."3" = sums.s3, p."4" = sums.s4, p."5" = sums.s5
```

This will modify all your duplicated rows to be the same, with each column having the sum of the original rating counts. So all you have left to do is erase a bunch of duplicates, except for one. That has been asked a few times on StackOverflow, for example:

- [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)
- [How can I delete one of two perfectly identical rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438323/how-can-i-delete-one-of-two-perfectly-identical-rows)

My personal favorite is:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE product ADD UNIQUE INDEX ("Product ID")
```

Comment: Thanks for this I get this error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"1") AS s1, SUM(product."2") AS s2, SUM(product."3' at line 4 when I try and run this and I'm not sure what it means?

Comment: @BenPaton That is caused by your column names. Seems that " only escapes characters if a ANSI_QUOTES is enabled. Can you try again with the backtick (`) instead?

Comment: alter ignore is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a really easy way to do it was to export all the data into csv and open in excel and use the consolidate data function in excel then re-import back into MySQL. Not using SQL to make the amends but it was quicker and easier in the end.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest creating a **view** instead of combining the rows? That way you have your original data, in case you need it.