# How to delete duplicate records in Snowflake database table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I delete the duplicate records from a Snowflake table?

```
ID Name
1  Apple
1  Apple
2  Apple
3  Orange
3  Orange
```

Result should be:

```
ID Name
1  Apple
2  Apple
3  Orange
```

Answer (score 31):

Adding here a solution that **doesn't recreate** the table. This because recreating a table can break a lot of existing configurations and history.

Instead we are going to delete only the duplicate rows and insert a single copy of each, within a transaction:

```sql
-- find all duplicates
create or replace transient table duplicate_holder as (
    select $1, $2, $3
    from some_table
    group by 1,2,3
    having count(*)>1
);

-- time to use a transaction to insert and delete
begin transaction;

-- delete duplicates
delete from some_table a
using duplicate_holder b
where (a.$1,a.$2,a.$3)=(b.$1,b.$2,b.$3);

-- insert single copy
insert into some_table
select * 
from duplicate_holder;

-- we are done
commit;
```

Advantages:

- Doesn't recreate the table
- Doesn't modify the original table
- Only deletes and inserts duplicated rows (good for time travel storage costs, avoids unnecessary reclustering)
- All in a transaction

Comment: Thanks for this - I am using a variant, `create duplicate_holder as ( select * ... qualify (row_number() over (partition by some_key)) = 2 `. Advantage is the ability to write a select * which is handy for wide tables.

Comment: I liked this solution but it misses the ability to look for duplicates using specific PK fields as reference. I have modified the solution to take care of it. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71515946/11608962)!

Comment: @Jarrad could you provide a code snippet of your code for handling wide tables?

Comment: No sorry, this was for work and I have since changed jobs.

Comment: Don't forget to drop `duplicate_holder` once you've verified the result.

Comment: ahh, I could have used `create or replace temp table` with `temp` for automatic deletion

Answer (score 22):

Here's a very simple approach that doesn't need any temporary tables.   It will work very nicely for small tables, but might not be the best approach for large tables.

```
insert overwrite into some_table
select distinct * from some_table
;
```

The `OVERWRITE` keyword means that the table will be truncated before the insert takes place.

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't rated higher since it works perfectly with the least amount of code.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I really like this -- and to extend it by de-duplicating by primary keys (which is my case, the records aren't identical as we have a load time column), it's easy to add a qualify with row-number combo into the `SELECT`

Comment: I have just had a problem with this solution where a masking policy was in place and the updated data contained the data from the masking policy, and not the original data. This was a problem unique to our configuration where the role I was using had write access to the table but couldn't actually see the data in some of the columns. Good solution generally but problematic in some instances.

Answer (score 13):

If you have some primary key as such:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit (key number, id number, name text);

insert into fruit values (1,1, 'Apple'), (2,1,'Apple'),
      (3,2, 'Apple'), (4,3, 'Orange'), (5,3, 'Orange');
```

as then

```
DELETE FROM fruit
WHERE key in (
  SELECT key 
  FROM (
      SELECT key
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY key) AS rn
      FROM fruit
  )
  WHERE rn > 1
);
```

But if you do not have a unique key then you cannot delete that way. At which point a

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
SELECT id, name FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,name
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name) AS rn
    FROM table_name
)
WHERE rn > 1
```

and then [swap](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html) them

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SWAP WITH new_table_name
```

Comment: Combining WITH ... AS and DELETE throws and error for me, `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 10 at position 0 unexpected 'DELETE'.`. I think you can only use SELECT, see https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/with.html#anchor-clause

Comment: quite fair point, I've not tested it, but given the CTE is not common (used more than once) it can just be pushed into a sub-select with a WHERE key IN (SELECT...) form

Comment: very true, replaced with a subselect.

Comment: Why `ALLOW_DUPLICATE` is just for JSON file-format and not for all the other file-formats? @SimeonPilgrim

Comment: @Vishrant it appears that comment is a unrelated question, that perhaps would be best suited to a new question??

Answer (score 7):

Snowflake does not have effective primary keys, their use is primarily with ERD tools.
Snowflake does not have something like a ROWID either, so there is no way to identify duplicates for deletion.

It is possible to temporarily add a "is_duplicate" column, eg. numbering all the duplicates with the ROW_NUMBER() function, and then delete all records with "is_duplicate" > 1 and finally delete the utility column.

Another way is to create a duplicate table and swap, as others have suggested.
However, constraints and grants must be kept.  One way to do this is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table COPY GRANTS;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table;
ALTER TABLE old_table SWAP WITH new_table;
```

The code above removes *exact* duplicates.  If you want to end up with a row for each "PK" you need to include logic to select *which* copy you want to keep.

This illustrates the importance to add update timestamp columns in a Snowflake Data Warehouse.

Comment: In my experience duplicate deletion is mostly done manually so swapping the table and then setting the permissions is the easiest.

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates, use a merge() instead of an insert(), this will force an update to an existing key instead of adding  a duplicate record.

Answer (score 7):

this has been bothering me for some time as well. As snowflake has added support for qualify you can now create a dedupped table with a single statement without subselects:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit (id number, nam text);
insert into fruit values (1, 'Apple'), (1,'Apple'),
      (2, 'Apple'), (3, 'Orange'), (3, 'Orange');


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE fruit AS 
SELECT * FROM 
fruit 
qualify row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id, nam ORDER BY id, nam) = 1;
SELECT * FROM fruit;
```

Of course you are left with a new table and loose table history, primary keys, foreign keys and such.

Answer (score 3):

Based on above ideas.....following query worked perfectly in my case.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SCHEMA.table
 AS
SELECT
    DISTINCT * 
FROM
    SCHEMA.table
  ;
```

Comment: This is similar to [TobyLL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70625021/8213085), except it has the disadvantage that it'll drop all of the privileges, constraints, comments, and whatever else

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to: [How can I delete one of two perfectly identical rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438323/how-can-i-delete-one-of-two-perfectly-identical-rows) . You can't. You can only do a `DELETE FROM fruit where ID = 1 and Name = 'Apple';`, then both rows will go away. Or you don't, and keep both.

For some databases, there are workarounds using internal rows, but there isn't any in snowflake, see https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008FQyGqSAL/is-there-an-internalmetadata-unique-rowid-in-snowflake-that-i-can-reference . You cannot limit deletes, either, so your only option is to create a new table and swap.

---

Additional Note on Hans Henrik Eriksen's remark on the importance of update timestamps: This is a real help when the duplicates where added later. If, for example, you want to keep the newer values, you can then do this:

```
-- setup
create table fruit (ID Integer, Name VARCHAR(16777216), "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP_NTZ);
insert into fruit values (1, 'Apple', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp_ntz)
, (2, 'Apple', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp_ntz)
, (3, 'Orange', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp_ntz);
-- wait > 1 nanosecond
insert into fruit values (1, 'Apple', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp_ntz)
, (3, 'Orange', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp_ntz);

-- delete older duplicates (DESC)
DELETE FROM fruit
  WHERE (ID
  , UPDATED_AT) IN (
     SELECT ID
     , UPDATED_AT
     FROM (
         SELECT ID
         , UPDATED_AT
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_AT DESC) AS rn
         FROM fruit
     )
     WHERE rn > 1
  );
```

Comment: If the rows are identical then why not use that same trick, instead partition and order on just the ID field. Exactly which row is deleted might be non-deterministic but then they are identical so it doesn't matter

Comment: Another why to think about `DELETE` is that `DELETE` is just rewriting the table, thus the `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT DISTINCT` is of equal work in snowflake, as it reads all rows, and write all rows, except for the edge case where you only have a small subsection of the data being impacted, that a delete would have pruned (assuming some constriants)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is effective if you are looking at **one or few columns as primary key references** for the table.

```sql
-- Create a temp table to hold our duplicates (only second occurrence)
CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE temp_table AS (
  SELECT [col1], [col2], .. [coln]
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(
      PARTITION BY [pk]1, [pk]2, .. [pk]m
      ORDER BY [pk]1, [pk]2, .. [pk]m) AS duplicate_count
      FROM [schema].[table]
  ) WHERE duplicate_count = 2
);


-- Delete all the duplicate records from the table
DELETE FROM [schema].[table] t1
USING temp_table t2
WHERE 
  t1.[pk]1 = t2.[pk]1 AND 
  t1.[pk]2 = t2.[pk]2 AND
  ..
  t1.[pk]n = t2.[pk]m;

-- Insert single copy using the temp_table in the original table
INSERT INTO [schema].[table]
SELECT * 
FROM temp_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by @Felipe Hoffa's answer:

```
##create table with dupes and take the max id
create or replace transient table duplicate_holder as (
select max(S.ID) ID, some_field, count(some_field) numberAssets
from some_table S
group by some_field
having count(some_field)>1
)

##join back to the original table on the field excluding the ID in the duplicate table and delete. 
delete from some_table as t
USING duplicate_holder as d
WHERE t.some_field=d.some_field
  and t.id <> d.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if people are still interested in this but I've used the below query which is more elegant and seems to have worked

```
create or replace table {{your_table}} as 
select * from {{your_table}}
qualify row_number() over (partition by {{criteria_columns}} order by 1) = 1
```