# Is there a functionality similar to ctid in postgres for MySQL/Snowflake or other databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to remove duplicates from the table but I need more of a generalized way of doing it. There are numerous ways to do it if the table has a unique identifier like row ID. But otherwise, it seems to be very difficult and different for different databases.

I even explored CTE (Common Table Expressions) to do the same but seems that databases do not allow the use of CTE followed by `DELETE` clause (at least what I saw with MySQL and Snowflake).

But in PostgreSQL, there seems to be a way in which we can achieve this without necessarily having any unique identifier. This is through the use of `ctid`, a [system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) in PostgreSQL. I am curious if there is a similar functionality like `ctid` for other databases especially MySQL and Snowflake is what I am interested in currently.

Comment: no there is not a CTID

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259580/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-snowflake-database-table

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Thanks for the suggestion but I have been doing something similar until now and wanted to eliminate the process of creating any additional table. It seems like there is not much control without the unique identifier.

Comment: Yes,  you need a plan to deal with duplicates.

Comment: You ether need to never insert duplicates, or have an id on the table to order by and match for a delete.

Comment: MySQL have such inner 6-byte row number (GEN_CLUST_INDEX) when there is no unique indices in the table, but it is absolutely inaccessible. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: Got it @SimeonPilgrim

Comment: Thanks, Still adds value to my knowledge @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am curious if there is a similar functionality like `ctid` for other databases especially MySQL and Snowflake is what I am interested in currently.

There is no `CTID` in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

There is ctid is Netezza and, i suppose, other databases based on postgresql