# How do I remove duplicates from this data in snowflake?

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]

I have this data where I have to remove the duplicate data highlighted in yellow. I tried to use distinct and group by but it does not seem to work.

Even though the comment and value is different, anything having the value as CRIMSSTANDARD is considered a child of the parent in this case and hence considered as a duplicate as the first 6 fields are the same. How do I remove the duplicate records in this case?

```
CLIENT;CLIENT_ID;QTY_TYPE;QUANTITY;AMOUNT;TRANTYPE;COMMENT;VALUE;ORDER_ID;DEV_COMM;AMT_COMM;ID
TEST_IMPL8;P-AGNIndPlusFd;A;;140000;Sell;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10902601;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-AGNIndPlusFd;Q;2898;;Buy;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10902701;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-AGNIndPlusFd;A;;140000;Sell;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10902601;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-DepVz;A;;82000;Sell;GEN,TransferOrder;10902568;Y;0;
TEST_IMPL8;P-DepVz;A;;82000;Sell;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10902568;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-DivBnd2Vv;A;;4862.09;Buy;GEN;OHPEN_14613296BD001571;10902668;;;14613296BD001571
TEST_IMPL8;P-DivBnd2Vv;A;;4862.09;Buy;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10902668;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-Dyn4Vz;A;;13000;Buy;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10877286;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-EmuCoInsBVv;Q;524.6892;;Sell;GEN;OHPEN_14613296BD001565;10677375;;;14613296BD001565
TEST_IMPL8;P-EmuCoInsBVv;Q;524.6892;;Sell;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;10677375;;;
TEST_IMPL8;P-VNAMijBel;Q;10236;;Sell;INS;CRIMSSTANDARD;11402183;;;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `distinct on` in Snowflake, but you can have a similar result using `qualify`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY client, client_id, qty_type, quantity, amount, trantype, value 
  ORDER BY client, client_id, qty_type, quantity, amount, trantype, value
) = 1;
```

See [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-produce-same-output-of-SELECT-DISTINCT-ON-statement-on-Snowflake) to see more details

**EDIT:**

To keep the rows that have the `dev_comm`, `amt_comm` and `ID` non null in priority you can modify your order condition:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY client, client_id, qty_type, quantity, amount, trantype, value 
  ORDER BY 
    IFF(dev_comm IS NOT NULL, 0, 1), 
    IFF(amt_comm IS NOT NULL, 0, 1), 
    IFF(ID IS NOT NULL, 0, 1)
) = 1;
```

You can also have different priorities by ordering the fields in the `order by`. For example in case you have multiple lines that have the `dev_comm` columns but you want in priority the line that have the `ID`, you need to put the `iff(ID ...` first in your `order by`. It order by the first element, then if there is several lines with the same first element it order by the second, etc...

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I get 8 records but I am getting the records included that I wanted to remove and the unique records with the dev_comm,amt_comm and ID fields are getting deleted instead. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Please post sample data in text, so someone trying to answer can use and test same easily.

Comment: You can use the one shared by @robin, replace '=' with '>' and also add condition as per your question before QUALIFY clause -  where value = 'CRIMSSTANDARD'

Comment: @Pankaj added sample data in text

Comment: @drv236 I edited my answer to order to have you columns not null in priority

Answer (score 1):

First pass, you'll need to get rid of rows that are entire duplicates of each other (this will fix the row 1 and row 3 issue in your data where the rows are exactly the same).  Use the approach outlined here: [How to delete Duplicate records in snowflake database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259580/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-snowflake-database-table/65743216#65743216)

Next, try this to eliminate duplicates of first 6 columns, and deleting the child record designated by CRIMSSTANDARD in the COMMENT column:

```
begin work;
delete from
    my_table using (
        select
            CLIENT,
            CLIENT_ID,
            QTY_TYPE,
            QUANTITY,
            AMOUNT,
            TRANTYPE
        from
            my_table
        GROUP BY
            CLIENT,
            CLIENT_ID,
            QTY_TYPE,
            QUANTITY,
            AMOUNT,
            TRANTYPE
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    ) as my_table_dupes
where
    my_table.CLIENT = X.CLIENT
    AND my_table.CLIENT_ID = my_table_dupes.CLIENT_ID
    AND my_table.QTY_TYPE = my_table_dupes.QTY_TYP
    AND my_table.QUANTITY = my_table_dupes.QUANTITY
    AND my_table.AMOUNT = my_table_dupes.AMOUNT
    AND my_table.TRANTYPE = my_table_dupes.TRANTYPE
    AND my_table.COMMENT = 'CRIMSSTANDARD' 
commit work;
```