# ROWID equivalent in Snowflake to delete duplicate lines

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rowid

I have a database with duplicate lines. I usally use the rowid, but it doesn't exist in Snowflake.
How can I remove duplicate lines in Snowflake without this ?
I try severals solution for the moment but without sucess !
Tanks

Comment: So what have you tried? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write and explain what issue you are facing. Hint: have a look at Window functions and row_number

Comment: Have a look if this solution works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259580/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-snowflake-database-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no equivalent to the ROWID in Snowflake.A Workaround is to do a select distinct and then insert the result in the same table.

```
insert overwrite into some_table
select distinct * from some_table;
```

Comment: That would be one way of doing it, if you don't want to go down the row_number route I suggested. Rather than update the table in place, I would clone your current table and then insert overwrite to that. Then you still have your original table to compare your changes to and, once you're happy with the results then you can rename the tables to "swap" them - so your new table is now your old table

Comment: I would do what @NickW is suggesting, except I would use the clone as the "comparison" and run the `insert overwrite` into your original table.  This gives you the comparison, but your final table retains all of your file history and time-travel.