# How to delete rows from table where some columns (but not all) are duplicate in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read previous questions but they are not similar to mine ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql) this has no unique identifier while I have) .

say this are my tables rows:

```
  id     string       x    y    z    time_x                 
10318    'hello'   33700  5053  8  2015-07-03 12:39:49.61408
14071    'hello'   33700  5053  8  2015-07-03 12:39:49.61408
```

basically everything is the same except the id of the row.
How can I identify these cases and delete the redundant rows?

Note: not all rows in table are duplicated. Regular rows should be left as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777633/delete-duplicate-rows-dont-delete-all-duplicate

Comment: @hruske this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let say that table name is tbl

`Delete from tbl where id not in (select min(id) from tbl group by string,  x,  y,  z)`

Answer (score 0):

This query uses window function to find duplicated rows. It leaves the row with smallest id:

```
delete from foo_table where id in (
    select dupid from (
        SELECT lead(id) over (partition by string, x, y, z, time_x order by id) dupid
        from foo_table
    ) A where dupid is not null 
);
```