# Remove all the duplicate values in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

mysql format :

```
        jcid_no           die_no          qty
       jcid-085951         12345            2
       jcid-085951         12345            2
```

Friends I've a table format as the above , I'll be continuously inserting the values into the table but my requirement is  I can insert n times same number of same jcid_no and die_no but not on the same row .

Valid example:

```
        jcid_no           die_no          qty
       jcid-085951         12345            2
       jcid-085951         54321            2


        jcid_no           die_no          qty
       jcid-085951         12345            2
       jcid-984301         12345            2
```

Same jcid_no different die_no and same die_no different jcid_no is ok but as if now my table got cluttered by have same table values multiple times my requirement is first I have to delete all the duplicate values that has been already inserted (i.e)

Wrong Format :

```
        jcid_no           die_no          qty
       jcid-085951         12345            2
       jcid-085951         12345            2
```

and the second thing is preventing this duplication for further enter , I use PHP as my front end .

Comment: select distinct into temp table. Delete. Copy back.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid further faulty values try using combined primary key like

```
PRIMARY KEY (jcid_no, die_no)
```

To delete double values try it with [self join delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011062/how-to-remove-duplicated-records-from-a-mysql-table).