# How to DELETE duplicate records in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)

I have a table with records and I want to delete all duplicate records

```
DELETE FROM 'table'
WHERE 'field' IN 
(
SELECT 'field' FROM 'table' GROUP BY 'field'
HAVING (COUNT('field')>1)
)
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Did you get an error message or did the query run successfully?

Comment: wouldnt your query delete all the fields including duplicates? if you have 2 duplicates with that ID your IN() query will delete both. Dont you wanna keep at least one record?

Comment: mysql doesn't let you update/delete on a table from which you're selecting data.

Comment: Table names must not be quoted with single quotes. `'table_name'` is a string literal. `table_name` is the name of a table.

Comment: can you add sample records? do you have auto_incremented columns?

Comment: thank a_horse_with_no_name, but now I get another error...

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: That's caused by MySQL's stupid limitations. See my answer.

Comment: Once you're done (with whatever answer works) make sure you add a `UNIQUE` constraint so you don't have to do this again in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can explore with the command [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/select.html) to select only unique records based in a field.

You can create a new table with the unique entries based. 
As an example...

```
CREATE TABLE nonDuplicates  
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM yourTable group by field
```

Comment: This will only work because MySQL's handling of GROUP BY is basically incorrect and allows for this invalid syntax. But it is most probably the fastest solution.

Comment: @vdhmartijn: please read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html  in order to understand *why* it's working in MySQL and why other DBMS would reject the statement as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you more than one result:-

```
SELECT field FROM `table`
GROUP BY field
HAVING (COUNT('field)>1
```

Try to chenge this by:

```
SELECT TOP 1 field
FROM `table`
GROUP BY field 
HAVING (COUNT(field)>1
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 doesn't work for me.. still not working

Comment: How does this delete anything?

Answer (score 0):

First get all duplicates and store them in array.

```
SELECT field 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY field
HAVING COUNT('field') > 1
```

now do your php to save one result whichever you want and then execute

```
DELETE 
FROM `table`
WHERE field IN (your values) AND field != savedID
```

Comment: Thanks for you reaction, but my intention is to work without PHP only SQL

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a very obnoxious restriction that cannot use the table that is being updated/deleted/inserted in a sub-select.

But you can work around this by joining the table to be deleted (instead of using a sub-select).

Assuming you have some kind of unique identifier in your table (I assume a column `id` in the following statement):

```
DELETE d 
FROM table_with_duplicates d 
JOIN ( 
   SELECT min(id) as min_id, field
   FROM table_with_duplicates 
   GROUP BY field
) keep ON keep.field = d.field
      AND keep.min_id <> d.id;
```

This will keep one row for each of the duplicates (the one with the lowes value in the `id` column).

If you want to delete *all* duplicate rows (not keeping at least one), simply remove the `AND keep.min_id <> d.id` condition.

**Edit**

If you don't have a unique column, but want to remove *all* duplicates (not keeping at least one row), then you can use:

```
DELETE d 
FROM table_with_duplicates d 
JOIN ( 
   SELECT field
   FROM table_with_duplicates 
   GROUP BY field
   HAVING count(*) > 1
) del ON del.field = d.field;
```

Comment: And if I do not have an ID is there still a way to solve this?

Comment: @vdhmartijn: If you want to delete **all** duplicates (not keeping at least one), then you can do without the ID. Otherwise see peixe's answer.