# trying to delete duplicate records in sql but the query is going in an infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my table test

```
id   identifier
---  ---------
1      zz
1      zzz
3      d 
5      w
7      v
8      q
9      cc
9      ccc
```

here I want to remove the duplicate id's and keep the latest id's.
the identifier can have duplicate values it dose not matter but the id's should be unique.

I wrote this query to solve this problem but the problem is that it goes into a infinite loop.

please help me with this as I am not able to see the error.
Thanks

```
 delete test
    from test
    inner join(
    select max(id) as lastId, identifier
    from test
    where id in (
              select id 
                from test
               group by id
              having count(*) > 1
       )
    group by id
    )dup on dup.id = test.id
    where test.id<dup.id
```

Comment: do you have a scenario that you have fully duplicated rows?

Comment: yes the id row is fully duplicated, but this issue is solved. wrote the above code to solve this issue worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I have found a solution for the issue: This is how I did it to solve the issue
This is the solution which worked for me when there are millions on entities in the table.
Any other SQL query is creating a lot of processes and burdening the server.

```
$i=0;
    while($i<10)
    {

        $statement="SELECT * 
                      FROM  test 
                      WHERE  id = :i";
        $query=$db->prepare($statement);
        $query->bindParam(':i',$i,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $c=count($results);
        $temp=$results[$c-1];

        $statement="DELETE FROM test WHERE id= :i";
           $query=$db->prepare($statement);
             $query->bindParam(':i',$i,PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $query->execute();

        $statement="Insert into test values(:id,:identifier)";
        $query=$db->prepare($statement);
             $query->bindParam(':id',$temp['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $query->bindParam(':identifier',$temp['identifier'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $query->execute();
             $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)

And try this one(works for you want to do), i did with the identifier column, but with the date column as shown in the post is better.

```
DELETE FROM Test WHERE Identifier NOT IN
    (SELECT MAX(Identifier) FROM Test GROUP BY Id);
```

Now with the DateField:

```
id   identifier   DateField
---  ---------    ----------
1      zz         2013-02-01
1      zzz        2013-03-02
3      d          2013-03-02
5      w          2013-03-02
7      v          2013-03-02
8      q          2013-03-02
9      cc         2013-01-15
9      ccc        2013-03-02
```

that is the table, and row (1, zzz) is newer than (1,zz), you can know it by the DateField column, then this query deletes two rows (1, zz) and (9, cc) the oldest for Id's 1 and 9.

```
DELETE FROM Test WHERE Datefield NOT IN
    (SELECT MAX(Datefield) FROM Test GROUP BY Id);
```

in SQL Server 2008 R2 i didnt get any error.

Comment: Geting an error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause. looked into the problem it basically says'cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery'

Comment: This will not work if there is fully duplicated rows or duplicated identifier or max(identifier) is not relating to the latest id.

Comment: Is there no way to work around? my original table contains about 300,000 records. and I need to remove the duplicate id's and keep the latest id's.

Comment: does your table have a date column?

Comment: No it has only 2 coulmns. I solved this issue. and updated the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on `test(id, identifier)`, the following should be pretty efficient:

```
delete from test
    where test.identifer < (select maxid 
                            from (select max(identifier) as maxid from test t2 where t2.id = t.id
                                 ) a
                           )
```

The double nested query is a MySQL trick for referencing the update/delete table in the same query.

Comment: No I dont have an index on     test(id,identifier) and this is also not working

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tb_name AS 
 SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(identifier ORDER BY id DESC),',',1) 
 FROM tb_name GROUP BY id ORDER BY NULL;

TRUNCATE TABLE tb_name;

INSERT INTO tb_name SELECT tmp_tb_name;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tb_name;