# Delete duplicates with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a structure like this:
It has a lot of duplicates, I highlighted two duplicates so you can get an idea. So what I want to do is delete all duplicates and leave only one copy: as you can see it's a table with episodes from TV shows. How can I do this with an SQL command? So basically the command will look for rows with same show_id and same season and episodes and delete all the duplicates except one (There are episodes with 3 copies of the same episode).

THE SCREENSHOT : [image: http://c74.img-up.net/dbdd4e.jpg]

Comment: I tried to find a command to do this, but i cant seem to find and I'm not really good at SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the duplicates by keeping all records except the one with the lowest id.  In MySQL you can do this with a `join` on `delete`:

```
delete t
    from <table> t left outer join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from <table t> t
          group by show_id, season, episode
         ) tokeep
         on t.id = tokeep.minid
    where tokeep.minid is null;
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a second!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution of getting a list of ids (1 from each group) and deleting everything else from this question: [How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY show_id, season, episode);
```

Comment: Updated with your fields

Answer (score 0):

You can also let MySql do the work for you adding `UNIQE` constraint using [`ALTER IGNORE TABLE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) syntax

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENGINE MyISAM; -- this obviously needed only if your ENGINE is not MyISAM
ALTER IGNORE TABLE Table1 ADD UNIQUE (`show_id`, `season`, `episode`);
ALTER TABLE Table1 ENGINE InnoDB; -- again this is only needed if your ENGINE was other than MyISAM
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eae61/1)** demo