# Deleting duplicate entries from postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a little trouble trying to delete multiple entries from my database which are very similar but not exactly the same. I have looked here and many other solutions:

[Delete Duplicate Records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-records-in-postgresql)

[How to delete duplicate rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)

Everytime I try to delete multiple duplicates from the table, The command removes all the entries instead of just removing the duplicates.

Here is the table with a duplicate sample, where we should only keep one unique hdrtime:

```
SELECT * from stdtextproducts where xxxid='DEN' AND nnnid='MTR' and hdrtime='270600';
 cccid |  datacrc   | hdrtime | nnnid | site | wmoid  | xxxid | bbbid |       inserttime        |                                 product                                  |    reftime    
-------+------------+---------+-------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------
 DEN   | 3680361181 | 270600  | MTR   | KDEN | SAUS70 | DEN   | RRF   | 2018-08-27 05:55:51.811 | SAUS70 KDEN 270600 RRF                                                  +| 1535349351811
       |            |         |       |      |        |       |       |                         | METAR KDEN 270553Z 22017KT 10SM BKN150 OVC200 23/06 A2991 RMK AO2 PK WND+| 
       |            |         |       |      |        |       |       |                         |      22026/0456 SLP028 T02330056 10289 20222 58004                       | 
 DEN   | 1538417601 | 270600  | MTR   | KDEN | SAUS70 | DEN   | RRM   | 2018-08-27 05:57:57.356 | SAUS70 KDEN 270600 RRM                                                  +| 1535349477356
       |            |         |       |      |        |       |       |                         | METAR KDEN 270553Z 22017KT 10SM BKN150 OVC200 23/06 A2991 RMK AO2 PK WND+| 
       |            |         |       |      |        |       |       |                         |      22026/0456 SLP028 T02330056 10289 20222 58004                       | 
(2 rows)
```

I have tried the following:

```
DELETE FROM stdtextproducts a USING (SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, hdrtime FROM stdtextproducts GROUP BY hdrtime HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b WHERE a.hdrtime = b.hdrtime AND a.ctid <> b.ctid;
```

And the following:

```
DELETE FROM stdtextproducts WHERE reftime NOT IN (SELECT MAX(reftime) FROM stdtextproducts GROUP BY hdrtime);
```

I should be expecting only one entry to show up on the list but it seems none of the entries are there anymore.

```
SELECT * from stdtextproducts where xxxid='DEN' AND nnnid='MTR' and hdrtime='270600';
 cccid | datacrc | hdrtime | nnnid | site | wmoid | xxxid | bbbid | inserttime | product | reftime 
-------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+---------+---------
(0 rows)
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DELETE FROM stdtextproducts  WHERE reftime NOT IN (SELECT MAX(reftime) FROM stdtextproducts b GROUP BY stdtxtproducts.hdrtime=b.hdrtime)

just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
  DELETE FROM stdtextproducts a where
   a.ctid<>   
    (SELECT MIN(b.ctid) as ctid
    FROM stdtextproducts b
    where a.hdrtime=b.hdrtime  
    )
```

or

```
   DELETE FROM stdtextproducts T1 
   USING   stdtextproducts  T2
    WHERE   T1.ctid < T2.ctid  -- delete the older versions
    AND T1.hdrtime= T2.hdrtime ;  -- add more columns if needed
```

Comment: I tried the 1st option, but it is taking too long. The 2nd option deletes everything in the table. Oh and T1.DEN should be T1.xxxid column.

Comment: @RayY for 2nd option you need key join and yes 1st one is too slow

Comment: Thanks it is working now, for others looking for the solution from google, I had tweaked your 2nd method a bit and came up with the following that works: DELETE FROM stdtextproducts a USING stdtextproducts b WHERE a.ctid < b.ctid AND a.site = b.site AND a.hdrtime = b.hdrtime AND a.nnnid = b.nnnid;

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM stdtextproducts a where
   exists 
    (SELECT *
    FROM stdtextproducts b
    where a.hdrtime=b.hdrtime 
    and b.ctid<a.ctid
    )
```

If this does not work, are you sure there isn't another `KEY` here besides just `hrdtime?`